# How to get high resolution R plot into Microsoft Word documents

Tags: r, plot

I'm using a macbook (version 10.11.6) and RStudio (Version 1.1.423 – © 2009-2018 RStudio, Inc.).

Whenever I use the plot function in RStudio, I get high quality graphics, but when I copy and paste or import the graphic into Microsoft Word 11, the graphic is no longer high quality. It looks awful. I can barely see the legend contents. Is there a way to export high quality graphics into Microsoft Word without losing the resolution?

```
sample code:

dose<- c(20, 30, 40, 45, 60)
drugA <- c(16, 20, 27, 40, 60)
par(family="serif")
plot(dose, drugA, type="b", lty=1, col=578)
legend(40, 20, c("random 0.865", 
                 "Random2  0.943"), 
       lty = c(1,3), col = c(578,84), 
       bty="o", cex=.50)
```

Edit: (I know how to increase plot resolution in R--I need to maintain the resolution when exporting into Microsoft Word)

This is a Microsoft Word 11 issue, but I'm leaving this question up because I initially thought it was an RStudio issue. Others might have the same question.

Comment: save as pdf, convert to high resolution png or tiff and copy to word

Comment: We have to assume that you have googled "r plot high resolution". Please clarify why these posts are not helpful. Cheers.

Comment: @Henrik Definitely googled that. No matter how much I increase the resolution of the graphic, when I export it into microsoft word, the quality is poor. I am writing my thesis and need to have acceptable (high quality) figures).

Comment: @r2evans Thanks, I know how to increase the resolution of a graphic. I need to know how to maintain that resolution of the graphic when importing into a Microsoft Word document.

Comment: I don't understand. If the graphic is produced with 600dpi at 1800x1200 and you tell word to import that specific PNG file, then ... what's the problem? Is it truly a problem for R (btw, the `[rstudio]` is wrong here) or is it something Word is doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds like this is an issue with Word, and nothing to do with R. You might want to ask this question as http://superuser.com/.

Comment: @r2evans You're right. The issue is Microsoft Word, not RStudio. All my word files were .docx. When I changed the file name to .doc, all my graphs are high resolution! I can even make out the information in the legend.                                                    https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_mac-mso_mac2011/losing-image-resolution-when-placing-an-image-into/0652113f-6b10-4819-8f3f-58fa6216dc8b

Comment: @r2evans  Could you please unmark this question as a duplicate? There might be other people asking the same question regarding plots made using RStudio when exporting into a Microsoft Word document. Again, this question is referring to maintaining the high resolution in Microsoft Word documents.

Comment: @jaap Could you please unmark this question as a duplicate? There might be other people asking the same question regarding plots made using RStudio when exporting into a Microsoft Word document. Again, this question is referring to maintaining the high resolution in Microsoft Word documents.

Comment: I still think it's not a valid question for SO: if it's about resolution in an R plot, then it is a duplicate; if it is about Word for Mac violating your imported images, then it's off-topic for SO. Either way, it's not valid. However, since there is a small chance that another Mac user may try to attribute this problem to R, and I've spent too much time stewing over it already, I'll retract my vote. If it is unlocked, I think you'll have a very short time to post a self-answer ... since somebody else might come behind me and trump my unvote. (Jaap has enough rep to completely trump me.)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is by saving as either a pdf (or another vector file, like svg), like so:

```
dose<- c(20, 30, 40, 45, 60)
drugA <- c(16, 20, 27, 40, 60)
par(family="serif")
pdf("drug_dose_1.pdf")
plot(dose, drugA, type="b", lty=1, col=578)
legend(40, 20, c("random 0.865", 
                 "Random2  0.943"), 
       lty = c(1,3), col = c(578,84), 
       bty="o", cex=.50)
dev.off()
```

Then import that file into Word. It'll keep its quality since the graph is a vector, not an image.

Comment: Thanks, I did this just now. When I imported the file into word, the quality of the graphic is still poor. How did you import the file into Microsoft Word? I have Microsoft word 11 for MacBooks (version 10.11.6). I imported the file by going to "Insert" -> "Photo" -> "Insert from file".

Comment: I'm on Linux, so I use LibreOffice Writer. Try perhaps saving as svg, it might have better support. Just change `pdf` to `svg` in the script. It should be something like Insert -> Image (instead of 'Photo')